# Same HTML, beautifying cause different result? What's happended?

Tags: html, css, struct, tree

This is working one (compressed):
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/t0ptc9uw/

And this is beautified one:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/zh7n875n/

Can anyone explain what just happened?

As far as I know extra line breaks / spaces should not affect HTML tags.

```css
#drive_main_init_spinner {
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      width: 50px
    }
    
    .a-Ba {
      height: 44px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative
    }
    
    .a-gn-Ba {
      height: 28px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -14px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      width: 28px;
      -webkit-animation: container-rotate 1.56s linear infinite;
      animation: container-rotate 1.56s linear infinite
    }
    
    .a-wa-xb {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      padding-top: 100px
    }
    
    .a-wa-xb .f-fd {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    .a-Ba-Tl {
      height: 44px;
      transition: transform .1s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
      -webkit-transition: transform .1s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1)
    }
    
    .a-Ba-wc {
      transform: scale(0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0)
    }
    
    .a-Ba-Gb {
      transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1)
    }
    
    .a-Nl-ka-Tl {
      transition: opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
      -webkit-transition: opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1)
    }
    
    .a-Nl-ka-So {
      opacity: .4
    }
    
    .a-Ba-hg-J {
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1
    }
    
    body #init-spinner-container {
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-top: 0
    }
    
    .ch-Pa-I {
      white-space: nowrap
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes container-rotate {
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes container-rotate {
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
    
    .Ba-kj {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0
    }
    
    .Ba-Sc {
      border-color: #4285f4
    }
    
    .Ba-hn {
      border-color: #db4437
    }
    
    .Ba-wn {
      border-color: #f4b400
    }
    
    .Ba-Em {
      border-color: #0f9d58
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-Sc {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-hn {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-wn {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-Em {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fill-unfill-rotate {
      12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg)
      }
      25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)
      }
      37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg)
      }
      62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg)
      }
      75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg)
      }
      87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fill-unfill-rotate {
      12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg)
      }
      25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
        transform: rotate(270deg)
      }
      37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
        transform: rotate(405deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
        transform: rotate(540deg)
      }
      62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg);
        transform: rotate(675deg)
      }
      75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
        transform: rotate(810deg)
      }
      87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg);
        transform: rotate(945deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
        transform: rotate(1080deg)
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes blue-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      26% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      89% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes blue-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      26% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      89% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes red-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      15% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      51% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes red-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      15% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      51% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      40% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      76% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes yellow-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      40% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      76% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes green-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      65% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes green-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      65% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    .Ba-Cm-dn {
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      top: 0;
      left: 45%;
      width: 10%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-color: inherit
    }
    
    .Ba-Cm-dn .Ba-cb {
      width: 1000%;
      left: -450%
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-color: inherit
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh .Ba-cb {
      width: 200%
    }
    
    .Ba-cb {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: inherit;
      border-bottom-color: transparent!important;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-animation: none;
      -webkit-animation: none;
      animation: none
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-gc .Ba-cb {
      border-right-color: transparent!important;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(129deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(129deg);
      transform: rotate(129deg)
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-Dc .Ba-cb {
      left: -100%;
      border-left-color: transparent!important;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-129deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-129deg);
      transform: rotate(-129deg)
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-gc .Ba-cb {
      -webkit-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-Dc .Ba-cb {
      -webkit-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes left-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes left-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
        transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
        transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
        transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes right-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes right-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
        transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
        transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
    }
    
    .Ba-ti {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0
    }
    
    .j-Ta-pb {
      position: relative;
      display: -moz-inline-box;
      display: inline-block
    }
```

```html
<div id="drive_main_init_spinner" class="a-Jf-Ma-m a-Da-wa-xb" tabindex="0">
    <div class="a-gn-Ba Ga">
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-Sc">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-hn">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-wn">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-Em">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because some of the elements are `inline-block;` which means the whitespace between them will honoured. Adding `font-size: 0;` to `#drive_main_init_spinner` will stop this from happening even with the whitespace as its size is reduced.

```css
#drive_main_init_spinner {
      font-size: 0;
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      width: 50px      
    }
    
    .a-Ba {
      height: 44px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative
    }
    
    .a-gn-Ba {
      height: 28px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -14px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      width: 28px;
      -webkit-animation: container-rotate 1.56s linear infinite;
      animation: container-rotate 1.56s linear infinite
    }
    
    .a-wa-xb {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      padding-top: 100px
    }
    
    .a-wa-xb .f-fd {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    .a-Ba-Tl {
      height: 44px;
      transition: transform .1s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
      -webkit-transition: transform .1s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1)
    }
    
    .a-Ba-wc {
      transform: scale(0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0)
    }
    
    .a-Ba-Gb {
      transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1)
    }
    
    .a-Nl-ka-Tl {
      transition: opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
      -webkit-transition: opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1)
    }
    
    .a-Nl-ka-So {
      opacity: .4
    }
    
    .a-Ba-hg-J {
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1
    }
    
    body #init-spinner-container {
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-top: 0
    }
    
    .ch-Pa-I {
      white-space: nowrap
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes container-rotate {
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes container-rotate {
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
    
    .Ba-kj {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0
    }
    
    .Ba-Sc {
      border-color: #4285f4
    }
    
    .Ba-hn {
      border-color: #db4437
    }
    
    .Ba-wn {
      border-color: #f4b400
    }
    
    .Ba-Em {
      border-color: #0f9d58
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-Sc {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, blue-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-hn {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, red-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-wn {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, yellow-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-kj.Ba-Em {
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both, green-fade-in-out 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fill-unfill-rotate {
      12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg)
      }
      25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)
      }
      37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg)
      }
      62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg)
      }
      75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg)
      }
      87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fill-unfill-rotate {
      12.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg)
      }
      25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
        transform: rotate(270deg)
      }
      37.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
        transform: rotate(405deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
        transform: rotate(540deg)
      }
      62.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg);
        transform: rotate(675deg)
      }
      75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
        transform: rotate(810deg)
      }
      87.5% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg);
        transform: rotate(945deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
        transform: rotate(1080deg)
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes blue-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      26% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      89% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes blue-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      26% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      89% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes red-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      15% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      51% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes red-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      15% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      51% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      40% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      76% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes yellow-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      40% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      76% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes green-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      65% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes green-fade-in-out {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      65% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      75% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
    
    .Ba-Cm-dn {
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      top: 0;
      left: 45%;
      width: 10%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-color: inherit
    }
    
    .Ba-Cm-dn .Ba-cb {
      width: 1000%;
      left: -450%
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-color: inherit
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh .Ba-cb {
      width: 200%
    }
    
    .Ba-cb {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: inherit;
      border-bottom-color: transparent!important;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-animation: none;
      -webkit-animation: none;
      animation: none
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-gc .Ba-cb {
      border-right-color: transparent!important;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(129deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(129deg);
      transform: rotate(129deg)
    }
    
    .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-Dc .Ba-cb {
      left: -100%;
      border-left-color: transparent!important;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-129deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-129deg);
      transform: rotate(-129deg)
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-gc .Ba-cb {
      -webkit-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    .Ga .Ba-cb-Gh.Ba-Dc .Ba-cb {
      -webkit-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      -webkit-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
      animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1) infinite both
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes left-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes left-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
        transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
        transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
        transform: rotate(130deg)
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes right-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes right-spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
        transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
        transform: rotate(-130deg)
      }
    }
    
    .Ba-ti {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0
    }
    
    .j-Ta-pb {
      position: relative;
      display: -moz-inline-box;
      display: inline-block
    }
```

```html
<div id="drive_main_init_spinner" class="a-Jf-Ma-m a-Da-wa-xb" tabindex="0">
    <div class="a-gn-Ba Ga">
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-Sc">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-hn">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-wn">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Ba-kj Ba-Em">
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-gc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-Cm-dn">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ba-cb-Gh Ba-Dc">
          <div class="Ba-cb Ba-ti"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4ouLhbga/

Comment: amazing, I just know `inline-block` will depends on whitespaces, thank you.